# How to use Mocha with webdriverjs in a valid environment

Tags: npm, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I installed all my software with `npm`.

But running mocha, it does not seem to find the `webdriverjs` module.
The only way to make it work, is by providing the full module path like this:

```
var webdriverjs = require('/var/www/mysite/linux/node/lib/node_modules/webdriverjs'),
    client = {};

describe('my webdriverjs tests', function(){ ...
```

How can I make node modules path available to an application like mocha ?

Thanks

Comment: `require('webdriverjs')` worked out of the box for me. You need to add more details so that we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Grunt, you can also install this package:
https://github.com/webdriverjs/grunt-webdriver

It will launch for you the selenium standalone server, create an instance of browser, and launch your mocha test.